# I cant validate this react form from adding values to input from browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, react-props

I try to fill and validate this form using javascript in browser console :
https://www.dacia.fr/contact/reserver-un-essai/coordonnees.html?modelURI=https%3A%2F%2Ffr.co.rplug.renault.com%2Fproduct%2Fmodel%2F52B%2Fsandero%2Fc%2FA-ENS_0MDL2P1SERIELIM4_-TERPL

The problem is that when I set a value to an input with

```
element.value = 'myvalue'
```

or

```
element.setAttribute('value', 'myvalue')
```

and I submit the form, this one is not validated.

Please help me, I tried everything. :(

I tried it too:
I tried it, but it didn't work. maybe I did something wrong ?

```
 var element = document.getElementById("contactFormFirstName");
    var ev = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
    element.value = "qsd";
    element.defaultValue = "qsd";
    element.dispatchEvent(ev);

    var element = document.getElementById("contactFormLastName");
    var ev = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
    element.value = "qsd";
    element.defaultValue = "qsd";
    element.dispatchEvent(ev);

    var element = document.getElementById("contactFormEmail");
    var ev = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
    element.value = "sqd@gmail.com";
    element.defaultValue = "sqd@gmail.com";
    element.dispatchEvent(ev);

    var element = document.getElementById("contactFormPhone");
    var ev = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
    element.value = "0612326546";
    element.defaultValue = "0612326546";
    element.dispatchEvent(ev);

    document.querySelector('form input[name="identity[title]"][value="M"]').checked = 'checked';
    document.querySelector('form input[name="identity[title]"][value="M"]').click();
    document.querySelector(' form input[name="optin[email]"][value="N"]').checked = 'checked';
    document.querySelector(' form input[name="optin[email]"][value="N"]').click();

document.querySelector('form button[type="submit"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting value, you have to trigger events - so react code will handle it as user input. For example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("contactFormFirstName");
var ev = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
element.value = "YYYY";
element.defaultValue = "YYYY";
element.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: I tried it (I modified the description of the thread with what i changed) but it didn't work. Did I do something wrong ? you can try it in console on the url of the form :/
I'm so desperate :D !

Comment: Maybe there's a way to simulate typing in the fields or something ? Or maybe react waits for a specific event ?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the input component : http://jerchassigneux-frontend.fr/screenshot.jpg